# How to add NavigationBar and keep position of infinite scroll on page change?

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter and I am learning from this sample code:

https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/infinite_list

I would like to modify it to have a NavigationBar with 2 pages. When I change the page, I want the position of the infinite scroll to stay where it was, but I cannot get it to work. Currently, I think my issue is that the structure of my code is bad, or similar. Causing a bad state tree that makes implementing what I am trying to do very difficult. How could I implement some way of remembering the scroll location in this code? Do you have any other pointers for how to improve this code? I am learning Flutter so any feedback is appreciated!

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'src/catalog.dart';
import 'views/home_page.dart';
import 'views/search_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Catalog>(
        create: (context) => Catalog(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
                seedColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 128, 0, 1)),
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

//This class is never means to change during execution
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var currentPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        indicatorColor: theme.primaryColor,
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'Feed',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: <Widget>[
        HomePage(theme: theme),
        SearchPage(theme: theme),
      ][currentPageIndex],
    );
  }
}
```

home_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../src/api/item.dart';
import '../src/catalog.dart';
import '../src/item_tile.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.theme,
  });

  final ThemeData theme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: theme.colorScheme.background,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Selector<Catalog, int?>(
        selector: (context, catalog) => catalog.itemCount,
        builder: (context, itemCount, child) => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var catalog = Provider.of<Catalog>(context);

            return switch (catalog.getByIndex(index)) {
              Item(isLoading: true) => const LoadingItemTile(),
              var item => ItemTile(item: item)
            };
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

search_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage({
    super.key,
    required this.theme,
  });

  final ThemeData theme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: theme.colorScheme.background,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const Text(
        'This is the search page',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a PageView widget to manage the pages and maintain the scroll position separately for each page.